# Can't change tomcat 7 heap size 

Tags: linux, tomcat, tomcat7, heap-memory

I have set the heap size of tomcat 7 by adding the following line in `catalina.sh`

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"
```

then stopped and started the tomcat.
but when tried to get the heap size using the command jmap -heap , i can notice that the memory doesn't change:

```
Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio = 70
   MaxHeapSize      = 526385152 (502.0MB)
   NewSize          = 1048576 (1.0MB)
   MaxNewSize       = 4294901760 (4095.9375MB)
   OldSize          = 4194304 (4.0MB)
   NewRatio         = 2
   SurvivorRatio    = 8
   PermSize         = 16777216 (16.0MB)
   MaxPermSize      = 67108864 (64.0MB)

Heap Usage:
PS Young Generation
Eden Space:
   capacity = 99352576 (94.75MB)
   used     = 9643144 (9.196418762207031MB)
   free     = 89709432 (85.55358123779297MB)
   9.705982862487632% used
From Space:
   capacity = 4063232 (3.875MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 4063232 (3.875MB)
   0.0% used
To Space:
   capacity = 5177344 (4.9375MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 5177344 (4.9375MB)
   0.0% used
PS Old Generation
   capacity = 37748736 (36.0MB)
   used     = 21889008 (20.874984741210938MB)
   free     = 15859728 (15.125015258789062MB)
   57.98606872558594% used
PS Perm Generation
   capacity = 60948480 (58.125MB)
   used     = 31496008 (30.03693389892578MB)
   free     = 29452472 (28.08806610107422MB)
   51.67644541750672% used
```

please advise.

Comment: did you add this at the beginning of the `catalina.sh` after all the `#` commented lines?

Comment: something wrong somewhere, it shows your NewSize at 4000 MB out of a total heap of 500 MB. you doing jmap on the right process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set additionally `export JAVA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"` and use [JConsole](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/jconsole.html) to inspect the tomcats memory consumption.

Comment: @sword101 Its a diagnostic tool from SUN/Oracle which allows to inspect the memory consumption of a JVM, too.

Comment: @sword101 Did you accidently set the JAVA_OPTS environment variable, too, with other values?

Comment: How does this answer answer the question?

Answer (score 63):

```
sudo vi /etc/default/tomcat7
```

Find the line that begins `JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true`

and change the piddly `-Xmx128m` to `-Xms512m -Xmx1024m`

If you have more than one core...`-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` is probably what you want.

Comment: If you've installed from apt-get, this is the correct answer.  No need to edit other scripts!

Comment: Or /etc/tomcat7/tomcat7.conf if you are on an rpm distribution.

Comment: This didn't work on my Ubuntu 12.04 (having installed via apt-get): Editing `/etc/default/tomcat7 had no effect. Editing `etc/default/tomcat7` worked.

Comment: This helped me to no end, i was doing all the OPTS etc etc, then you showed me this omg :) It couldn't even deploy the tools...

Comment: This is great information even today in Ubuntu 18.04, Tomcat 8.  Thanks so much for this.

Answer (score 49):

Do not change `catalina.sh`**!!** This file is not supposed to be changed by user. Tomcat updates may override it. Instead create a file called "**setenv.sh**" in your "$CATALINA_BASE/bin" (same folder as `catalina.sh`). Set all your environment variables there.

`setenv.sh` is an optional file. If it exists it gets imported by `catalina.sh`. And the name suggests what you put there. This is a proper place to initialize your $CATALINA_OPTS, $JAVA_OPTS, etc.

P.S. Generally speaking you should avoid tweaking files that can can change with package/distribution update provided and alternative configuration approach exists. In this case files like `catalina.sh`, `/etc/tomcat7/tomcat7.conf`, `/etc/init.d/tomcatX` etc can be updated silently and you won't even notice that your configuration changes are rolled back.

Answer (score 18):

how about editing etc/default/tomcat7

```
# You may pass JVM startup parameters to Java here. If unset, the default
# options will be: -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
#
# Use "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC" to enable the CMS garbage collector (improved
# response time). If you use that option and you run Tomcat on a machine with
# exactly one CPU chip that contains one or two cores, you should also add
# the "-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode" option.
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1280m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
```

Comment: Best place to configure heap of tomcat 7 on ubuntu.

Comment: digz6666: Care to elaborate on that?

Comment: This is the correct place to configure the heap (and logging properties, and much more) for tomcat7 in ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Goto your catalina.sh

Add these line at the beginning

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-server -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
-XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
```

Then start your tomcat using startup.sh

Comment: see the answer by cherio. don't change catalina.sh. i just got bitten by this today when i upgraded tomcat and a change to catalina.sh was reverted