# TomCat-unable to create Java Virtual Machine error

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

After I recently tried to install TomCat and use it in Eclipse, I was not able to run the server as it prompts an error that says "Could not create Java Virtual Machine".

After reading other's solutions I tried adding a _JAVA_OPTIONS in system variable but it didn't work either.

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: You can look through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459945/how-to-solve-could-not-create-the-virtual-machine-error-of-java-virtual-machine) or this [question](http://www.tomsguide.com/faq/id-1761312/fix-create-java-virtual-machine-issue.html).

Comment: This same question has been asked before on SO

Comment: Which versions of Tomcat, Eclipse, and Java are involved?

Comment: @nitind all the latest versions. Tomcat 9, jdk 10, eclipse oxygen.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50094645/27905