# Couldn't create the Java Virtual Machine on Windows 10 when starting Tom Cat Server 8.0

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, windows-10, eclipse-oxygen

I have installed Java EE, Eclipse Oxygen and added Tom Cat Server 8.0 onto Eclipse. After that, I have tried starting the TomCat server and got the below error message.

[image]

I have tried changing the port numbers as well on Overview window but still, there is no luck. Could anyone share some thoughts on how to resolve this?

Comment: what version of java are you using?

Comment: Using Java 10.0.1

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459945/how-to-solve-could-not-create-the-virtual-machine-error-of-java-virtual-machine at the bottom. It looks similar issue  as yours. It looks Using `jdk-8u172-windows-x64` could solve this

Comment: I have already that system variable but still no luck. :(

Comment: Are you able to start the Tomcat server on the command line?

Comment: Do you have a line-break in JAVA_OPTIONS?

Comment: No Pavel. there is no line break...

Comment: @jplosa Nope. When I try running localhost:8080 I am asked for username password..

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50094645/27905 . Eclipse Photon, which comes out Wednesday, will also contain the fix.