# Trying to launch Logstash on Windows, but gives errors

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

I'm trying to launch logstash via CMD. I have the right directory, but when I enter `logstash.bat` command to launch it gives the following errors (see in the picture):

[image]

Please help me out.

Comment: Does https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/51361#issuecomment-704208369 thread solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the given error, I think the problem is with Java not with Logstash. Maybe you can try solving it from this [How to solve could not create the virtual machine error of Java Virtual Machine Launcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459945/how-to-solve-could-not-create-the-virtual-machine-error-of-java-virtual-machine)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because Logstash is using the Java distribution you have installed on your machine, which jdk-15.0.1.

However, Logstash [does not support that version](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/getting-started-with-logstash.html#ls-jvm) (only 8, 11 and 14).

So, in your terminal I would just unset the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable so that the JDK bundled with Logstash can be used instead.

```
set JAVA_HOME=
```

And then try to start Logstash again