# Tomcat throws OutOfMemoryError on startup

Tags: tomcat, jvm, tomcat7

**Error and trace:**

I am seeing the following `OutOfMemoryError` error when trying to start up Tomcat 7.0.28 on a Windows 32-bit machine:

```
SEVERE: Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of WAR files to complete
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap s
pace
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:752
)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:472
)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1413)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java
:313)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
eSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa
se.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase
.java:401)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:34
6)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
va:1159)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java
:785)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1585)
...
```

Please let me know if you need more of the trace.

**What I have tried:**

I have tried to follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897476/tomcat-7-how-to-set-initial-heap-size-correctly) to [this question about my `OutOfMemoryError`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771701/war-file-throws-outofmemoryerror-in-tomcat-server) but have been unsuccessful. More specifically, following the directive in `catalina.sh`...

```
#   Do not set the variables in this script. Instead put them into a script
#   setenv.sh in CATALINA_BASE/bin to keep your customizations separate.
```

...I created `setenv.sh` in `CATALINA_BASE/bin`. The entire contents of that file are:

```
SET CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xms512M -Xmx1024M"
```

After restarting the server, I am seeing the same error. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you use Windows, but you have created a Unix shell script ".sh". Rename it to ".bat". The set command should look like this:

```
SET "CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Xms512m -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```