# Tomcat won't deploy an application due low java heap memory

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, deployment, war

I want to deploy my `.war` (cca 55MB) application to apache tomcat 7 application server, nevertheless the deployment fails. When I try to deploy some smaller `.war` archive (cca 4MB), it finishes without any problem. I've tried to increase `java heap` space and now it should be quite enough. Moreover after the attempt to deploy this `.war`, even `tomcat manager` crashes. I'd be glad for any suggestion how to solve this.

```
root@vm15187:~# java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize|PermSize|ThreadStackSize'
uintx AdaptivePermSizeWeight                    = 20              {product}
 intx CompilerThreadStackSize                   = 0               {pd product}
uintx ErgoHeapSizeLimit                         = 0               {product}
uintx HeapSizePerGCThread                       = 87241520        {product}
uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 65019648        {product}
uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold                = 134217728       {product}
uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 1042284544      {product}
uintx MaxPermSize                               = 174063616       {pd product}
uintx PermSize                                  = 21757952        {pd product}
 intx ThreadStackSize                           = 1024            {pd product}
 intx VMThreadStackSize                         = 1024            {pd product}
 java version "1.7.0_75"
 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.4) (7u75-2.5.4-1~deb7u1)
 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

In my `catalina.out` log are these error messages:

```
SEVERE: Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of WAR files to complete
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space


SEVERE: Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of directories to completehostConfig.deployWar=Deploying web application archive {0}
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Full log [here](http://pastebin.com/8Fg7rhQu)

Comment: What have you done to increase the memory allocation?

Comment: I assume that it's not the size of the WAR itself, but what is done during the deployment that uses up the heap space.

Comment: @SteveC I used something like this `JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dfile.encoding=UTF8"`

Comment: @Geziefer Yes...it crashes during the deployment, but only when I'm trying to deploy a large archive. Tiny archives don't cause any problems.

Comment: Solution by @spanky found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398053/cant-change-tomcat-7-heap-size/10950387#10950387

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to continue increasing the memory allocation `-XmxNNNNm` until it works and then use a memory analysis tool to learn what is consuming it. In my experience a 55MB WAR file is a sizeable application.

Note that you should use:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms..."
```

instead of JAVA_OPTS. This latter environment variable is applied to all java processes that are launched to support Tomcat. CATALINA_OPTS is only applied to the server process.

Comment: I've tried to set `CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms4096m"` but the problem still persists and in logs are the same errors.