# There is no etc/default/tomcat7 file and not able to increase heap size in tomcat 7 linux?

Tags: java, linux, out-of-memory, tomcat7, heap-memory

I have installed tomcat7 to my system.Now I am getting

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2595)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2895)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:354)
```

I have try to update /etc/default/tomcat7 file but it is not in my system.

What can I do now?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398053/cant-change-tomcat-7-heap-size/10950387#10950387

Comment: @lvan I am not clear on this. Please explain. ;-)